# Passar variável entre arquivos PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Talvez essa pergunta seja duplicada, mas estou com esse problema. Peguei um projeto pra dar continuidade aqui no serviço e ele usa funções antigas como mysql_connect, mysql_querry e eu preciso trocar isso.
ex:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "",) or die ("Falha ao conectar ao banco de dados - ".mysql_error());
```

E ele usava um arquivo com uma função para fazer uma conexão com o banco, e o mysql_query não precisa passar uma conexão como parâmetro então funcionava, já o mysqli_query precisa de uma conexão, então toda vez que eu estou usando eu tenho que abrir uma nova conexão e depois fechar ao final do mysqli_query.

Enfim queria saber como faço para manter esse arquivo de conexão e enviar essa variavel $con para todos os arquivos que necessitar.
exemplo:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","db") or die ("Falha ao conectar ao banco de dados - ".mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Tentou dar um include/require?

Comment: Havia testado sim, mas sempre funcionava o primeiro e os demais não, eu estava fechando a conexão. Normal a gente pensar no erro só horas depois. De toda forma, muito obrigado

Comment: O mysqli_query [não necessariamente](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) requer passagem da conexão.